# Processing unknown amount of actors results on single timeout

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am looking to expand the following code to work for an unknown amount of actor ask requests.

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(100 millis)
val sendRequestActor = context.actorOf(Props(new SendRequest(request)), "Send_Request_".concat(getActorNumber))
val sendRequestActor2 = context.actorOf(Props(new SendRequest(request)), "Send_Request_".concat(getActorNumber))
val a1 = ask(sendRequestActor, Request).fallbackTo(Future.successful(RequestTimeout))
val a2 = ask(sendRequestActor2, Request).fallbackTo(Future.successful(RequestTimeout))
val result = for {
  r1 <- a1
  r2 <- a2
} yield(r1, r2)

val r = Await.result(result, 100 millis)
r match {
  case (b: SuccessResponse, b2: SuccessResponse) => {
    //Process Results
  }
  case (b: SuccessResponse, b2: RequestTimeout) => {
    //Process Results
  }
  case (b: RequestTimeout, b2: SuccessResponse) => {
    //Process Results
  }
  case (b: RequestTimeout, b2: RequestTimeout) => {
    //Process Results
  }
  case _ => {}
}
```

I am trying to send out requests to a List of recipients(gotten from a previous database call).  The number of recipients will vary each time this function is called.  Recipients have a maximum of 100 milliseconds to respond before I want to time out their requests and record a `RequestTimeout`.  The `SendRequest` actor will reply with `SuccessResponse` if the recipients respond.  I am assuming I will have to change the `val result` for-loop to process a list, but I am unsure of how to structure everything so that I will wait the minimum amount of time(either when all actors return or when the timeout hits, whichever is lower).  I do not need everything in a single return value like the example, I am fine with a list of results and matching type on each iteration.

Any help would be appreciated, please let me know if I can provide any other information.

Thank you

Edit:

Calling Class:

```
case object GetResponses

def main(args: Array[String]) {

val route = {
  get {
    complete {
      //stuff
      val req_list = List(req1,req2,req3)
      val createRequestActor = system.actorOf(Props(new SendAll(req_list)), "Get_Response_Actor_" + getActorNumber)
      val request_future = ask(createRequestActor, GetResponses).mapTo[List[Any]]
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      println(request_future)
      //more stuff
    }
  }
}


Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
}
```

Updated Sending Class:

```
class SendAll(requests: List[Request]) extends Actor {
  import context.{become,dispatcher}
  var numProcessed = 0
  var results: List[Any] = List()
  requests.foreach(self ! _)

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(100 millis)
  def receive = {

    case r: RequestMsg =>
      val sendRequestActor = context.actorOf(Props(new SendRequest(r)), "Send_Request_".concat(getActorNumber))
      (sendRequestActor ? Request).pipeTo(self)

    case s: SuccessResponse =>
      println("Got Success")
      results = results :+ s
      println(results.size + " == " + requests.size)
      if(results.size == requests.size) {
        println("Before done")
        become(done)
      }

    case akka.actor.Status.Failure(f) =>
      println("Got Failed")
      results = results :+ RequestTimeout
      if(results.size == requests.size) {
        become(done)
      }

    case m => 
      println("Got Other")

  }

  def done: Receive = {
    case GetResponses =>
      println("Done")
      sender ! results
    case _ => {
      println("Done as well")
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
Got Success
1 == 3
Got Success
2 == 3
Got Success
3 == 3
Before done
Future(<not completed>)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the list of requests to the actor, then [`pipe`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.6/scala/futures.html#use-with-actors) the responses from the child actors to `self` instead of using `Await.result`. For example:

```
class Handler(requests: List[RequestMsg]) extends Actor {
  import context.{become, dispatcher}
  var numProcessed = 0
  var results: List[Any] = List()
  requests.foreach(self ! _)

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(100.millis)

  def receive = {
    case r: RequestMsg =>
      val sendRequestActor = context.actorOf(Props(new SendRequest(r)), "Send_Request".concat(getActorNumber))
      (sendRequestActor ? Request).pipeTo(self)

    case s: SuccessResponse =>
      println(s"response: $s")
      results = results :+ s
      if (results.size == requests.size)
        become(done)

    case akka.actor.Status.Failure(f) =>
      println("a request failed or timed out")
      results = results :+ RequestTimeout
      if (results.size == requests.size)
        become(done)

    case m =>
      println(s"Unhandled message received while processing requests: $m")
      sender ! NotDone
  }

  def done: Receive = {
    case GetResponses =>
      println("sending responses")
      sender ! results
  }
}
```

You would instantiate an actor for every list of requests:

```
val requests1 = List(RequestMsg("one"), RequestMsg("two"), RequestMsg("three"))
val handler1 = system.actorOf(Props(new Handler(requests1)))
```

In this example--following the principle that an actor should have a distinct, limited sphere of responsibility--the actor simply coordinates requests and responses; it doesn't perform any processing on the collected responses. The idea is that another actor would send this actor a `GetResponses` messages in order to get the responses and process them (or this actor would proactively send the results to a processing actor).

Comment: This looks like it will do what I want.  But I am having a problem with the `done` function, it doesn't seem to be getting called at all(Doesn't seem to have to be the sleep timer).  I previously had another actor calling this function, and would be where the processing takes place.  I updated the OP to include my calling class as well as my updated sending class.  Any clue why I never see anything print from my done class as well as have my future not complete?

Comment: @Eumcoz: Regarding your update, a couple of notes: (1) Your `RequestHandler` looks odd in that it extends `Actor` and calls `system.actorOf` (`system.actorOf` should be called in the main program, not from within an actor). (2) You're probably not allotting enough time for the request-response handling to finish. Increase the `Thread.sleep` or use the `onComplete` callback on the `Future`.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, for some reason I thought this was being called from somewhere else, in my actual program `RequestHandler ` is my main, and is an akka-http handler.  `SendAll` is being called from a Directive from an http request.  No matter how long I sleep, it fails, my SendAll call timeout will kick in: `Failure(akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://HTTP_Actor_System/user/Get_Response_Actor_1#-720534280]] after [10000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "GetResponses$".)`  In previous testing my response takes about 5 ms to process.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is put all your actor refs into the `List` map it to `List[Future]` and use [Future.sequence](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#sequence[A,M[X]%3C:TraversableOnce[X]](in:M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]])(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]],A,M[A]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[M[A]]) to obtain `Future[List]`.

```
val route = {
  get {
    val listActorRefs = List(actorRef1, actorRef2, ...)
    val futureListResponses = Future.sequence(listActorRefs.map(_ ? Request))
    onComplete(futureListResponses) {
      case Success(listResponse) => ...
        complete(...)
      case Failure(exception) => ...
    }
  }
}
```

A better solution is avoid a lot of actor' asks, prepare some *ResponseCollector* actor which will send all your message (I suggest to look at BroadcastPool) and schedule one message for itself to stop waiting and return result.